# R: subset() returning different results for equivalent logical expressions

Tags: r, subset

While writing convenience functions for subset(), I ran into a strange situation where using equivalent logical statements returns different subsets.  So, for example:

```
dat = data.frame(ttl.stims = c(4,4,8,8), change = c('big', 'small'))
dat
ttl.stims = 4

#logical statements are equivalent
dat$ttl.stims == 4
dat$ttl.stims == ttl.stims

#subset evaluates differently
subset(dat, dat$ttl.stims == 4)
subset(dat, dat$ttl.stims == ttl.stims)
```

I've been working around this by doing:

```
index = dat$ttl.stims == ttl.stims
subset(dat, index)
```

But I'm so curious about why the first two subsets don't produce identical results!  Ideas?  Thoughts?  Pontifications?

Comment: From `?subset`: "Warning: ... in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument ‘subset’ can have unanticipated consequences."

Comment: possible duplicate of [In R, why is `\[` better than `subset`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because inside the call to `subset` the symbol `ttl.stims` gets interpreted in the environment of `dat`, so it becomes (after interpretation)  `dat$ttl.stims`. I predict that the second call to subset returns the entire dataframe.

Comment: Ah, I changed the name of `ttl.stims` and it worked.  Thanks for the insight--that's really good to know!  I definitely need to read more into how R evaluates function calls..

Comment: In this case all you need to know is that inside `subset` or a `with` call the interpreter looks first at column names for a match, and only if it doesn't find a match does it look to the parent.frame (which might or might not be the `.GlobalEnv`). The use of `with` is likewise considered dangerous inside functions.